# jsonpCallback not calling function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here's my jquery snippet that I can't get to work. I'm trying to call blackBackground() through jsonpCallback

```
$(document).ready(function()
{


    function blackBackground(data, status)
    {
        console.log("black background");
            //I want to eventually change the body style to black
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/someurl',
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'blackBackground'
    });

});
```

Update:

```
jsonpCallback: 'blackBackground'
```

to

```
jsonpCallback: blackBackground
```

along with moving blackBackground to global scope. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: *"Here's my JSONP"* that's JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: Is your server actually generating JSONP? Why do you need JSONP if you're not making a cross-domain request?

Comment: that's not the problem. Mistake on my part. Edited. I need JSONP because I want to be able to expand this to make a cross-domain request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the function `blackBackground` is not available in the global scope.

You can either expose the function in the global scope by declaring it like this:

```
window.blackFunction = function(){ .. }
```

...or use an anonymous function in the ajax configuration:

```
jsonpCallback: function(result){ .. }
```

I'd recommend the latter, as it will keep you global scope tidy a wee bit longer :)

Comment: I brought the blackBackground function out of the document ready function and it didn't work. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you should examine the request in a developer console. What is the request's status code and body?

Comment: The anonymous function worked, but when I tried to declare the global scope version like you said above, it didn't work. Why would that be?

Comment: Great :) It might have something to do with the server not responding with the desired function call?

Answer (score 2):

> "Here's my JSONP"

that's JSON, not JSONP.

Since you specified `jsonp: false`, you need to define the callback on the global scope yourself.

```
function blackBackground(data, status)
{
    console.log("black background");
        //I want to eventually change the body style to black
}
// document ready isn't really needed here either, but you can make that choice.
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/someurl',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'blackBackground'
    });

});
```

and your server should respond with:

```
blackBackground({
    "name": "async-poll",
    "description": "api for asynchronous polls",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x"
    }
})
```

Comment: tried that. The jsonp stuff was an accident. That's not the data it's supposed to respond with. The question isn't about data getting sent back. I don't know why the function isn't being called. Thanks

Comment: Then what is the server returning? if you want to define a function the way you mentioned, your server must return the jsonp in this format.

Comment: @tausch86 *"The question isn't about data getting sent back."* If the question is about why the callback isn't getting called, then the question is about the data that is being sent back. With JSONP, the data that is being returned from the server is literally javascript that executes the callback.

Comment: I guess I don't understand this is well as I had thought. How does the data control whether or not the callback function is called?

Comment: @tausch86 Maybe this will help. The following is an example of how jsonp would be implemented in native javascript: http://pastebin.com/8u3pE6zT

Answer (score 2):

Take off the single quotes

```
jsonpCallback: blackBackground
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`dataType: "jsonp"`</strike>

<strike>Is Not a valid dataType.</strike> To do jsonp you need to add `callback=?` to the URL query string

`url: 'http://localhost:3000/someurl?callback=?',`

Comment: jsonp is definitely a valid dataType.

Comment: sorry just read the first bit from the API which stated: dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

Comment: That threw me at first too, but that's just saying *Intelligent Guess* will be one of those 4.

Comment: haha, yup. thanks for the comment. Made me actually RTFM, I wasn't sure how to add a strike through via the WYSIWYG so I just pulled that bit of info.

Comment: for future reference, `<strike>...</strike>`